# Do we have an integration version of Weyl's inequality?

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis, integral-inequality

See [Lemma](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1063049/).

> Let $k_i$, $\lambda_i$ be non-negative numbers such that that $\lambda1\ge \lambda _2\ge \cdots\ge \lambda _m$, and $\lambda _1\le k_1$, $\lambda _1\lambda _2 \le k_1 k_2$, $\cdots$, $\lambda _1 \cdots \lambda _m\le k_1\cdots k_m$, then for any function $\varphi$ such that $\varphi(e^t)$ is a convex function of $t$ and $\varphi(0)=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\varphi(t) =0$, 
>   we have $$ \sum_{i=1}^m \varphi(\lambda )\le \sum_{i=1}^m \varphi(k_i).$$

I would like to ask whether we have an integration version of this result. e.g., something similar to the following:

Let $k(t)$, $\lambda(t)$ be two non-negative decreasing functions on $(0,\infty)$ such that that  $$\int_0^t\log \lambda (s)\,\mathrm ds \le \int_0^t \log k(s)\,\mathrm ds$$
for every $t>0$,
 then 
we have $$\int_0^t\log \varphi(\lambda (s))\,\mathrm ds \le \int_0^t \log \varphi(k(s))\,\mathrm ds$$

Comment: Have a look at http://www.tricki.org/article/The_van_der_Corput_lemma_for_oscillatory_integrals

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio  Thank you for your reply. However... I can't see any connection between my question and the link you gave me.

Comment: Actually I looked at the title only, and you seem to look for an integral version of [Karamata's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karamata%27s_inequality), rather than Weyl's inequality, which is an entirely different thing.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio   Well. So, is there an integral version of this Karamata's inequality?

Comment: Yes, there is: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1746326/44121

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio   It is very similar. However, in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1746326/relation-between-karamatas-and-hardy-littlewoods-inequalities       or   http://elib.mi.sanu.ac.rs/files/journals/tm/14/tm813.pdf      , the multiplication of two functions are considered (i.e. f(t)g(t)). But in my case, I consider $f(g(t))$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75076/discussion-between-user92646-and-jack-daurizio).

Comment: If this is about [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2702781/int-0s-log-ftdt-le-int-0s-log-gtdt-for-every-s-in-0-1-implies-t), there is no way to apply classical results for proving such inequality, since it does not hold with the given constraints.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio  Woo. Could you prove a reference for ' it does not hold with the given constraints' ?

Comment: I think the right column of P.568 of https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pjm/1102992404   is what I need...

Comment: By the the integral version of the
Hardy-Littlewood-Pólya  inequality 
 https://carma.newcastle.edu.au/jon/Preprints/Books/CUP/CUPold/np-convex.pdf